# How can I write hexadecimal data in the file so that additional data is not written (like hexeditors)?

Tags: c, binary, hex, hex-editors

I want to make something like a small hex editor for my project.

so i wrote a function like this(to replace the original code with the new code):

```
int replace(FILE *binaryFile, long offset, unsigned char *replaced, int length) {
    if (binaryFile != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            fseek(binaryFile, offset + i, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&replaced[i], sizeof(replaced), 1, binaryFile);
        }
        fclose(binaryFile);
        return 1;
    } else return -1;
}
```

So I wrote this code to test the function and sent it to address 0x0:

```
unsigned char code[] = "\x1E\xFF\x2F\xE1";
```

and i got this hexadecimal result:

```
1e ff 2f e1 00 10 2b 35 ff fe 07 00
```

But I don't need data after E1 (00 10 2b 35 ff fe 07 00)

How can I write the function so that only the data sent to the function is stored?

Comment: Are you combining both C and C++ languages?  Difficult thing to do, as C++ allows overloading of operators and functions whereas the C language doesn't.  I recommend using only one language, C++ and removing the other tag.

Comment: You may want to use this new technology, called *Boolean* type.  It's used when a variable can have a `true` or `false` state or to indicate success or failure.  Using an `int` is so 1960's.

Comment: I recommend using another recent language technology, declaring variables by size.  For example, if you need an unsigned 8-bit integer, the type would be `uint8_t`.  Other integer types are based on range, not bit-width.

Comment: I suspect you are passing `sizeof code` as the length to `replace`. We can see this because there are eight bytes beyond the last one you want. If the only problem were `sizeof(replaced)` being eight (for an eight-byte pointer), there would be seven bytes beyond the last one you want. What happened is `length` includes the terminating null byte, and then `replace` wrote that null byte plus seven more bytes. You will need to account for that—reduce the length passed to `replace` by one or define the array `code` so that it does not include a terminating null character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(replaced)` is wrong. `replaced` is a `unsigned char *`, so that's not the size you want.

You probably want `sizeof(unsigned char)` or `sizeof(*replaced)`.

Currently, you end up writing eight times too much.

Note that you could also write in a single step:

```
if (binaryFile != NULL) 
{
    fseek(binaryFile, offset, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(replaced, sizeof(unsigned char), length, binaryFile);
}
```